# Convert key-value map to type with required fields (or fail) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-safety

I have two types of interest, and a collection:

```
type One = {
    'type': 'One';
    a: string;
    x?: string;
}

type Two = {
    'type': 'Two';
    b: string;
    y?: string;
}

const collection: Map<string, string>[];
```

I expect the collection contains elements that are key-value maps matching a structure of the One or Two types; I am also not able to know this for certain in advance (some elements may match neither or have extra keys). Importantly, the most common error case is that an element is missing one of the required fields:

```
[ { 'type': 'One',
    'a': 'value',
    'x': 'another',
  },
  { 'type': 'Two',
    'b': 'value',
  },
  { 'type': 'One'
  }, // this element should error when the function is called
]
```

So it is not allowed to be more constrained in the type. However, I would like to write a function like `typeCastOrError(m: Map<keyof One | keyof Two,string>): One | Two` by constructing each option when possible, or throwing an error.

However I am not clear on how to do this. I might construct the type and iterate over its keys, but I can't construct it empty because the keys are required. I am using strictest tsconfig type checking.

How can I safely do type casting to a value with required types like this ?

Comment: the example collection is an array `[...]` not a `Map`

Comment: Using your array example, a discriminated union gets you there. Demo it on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdtAvFA3gKCpqByUlsBcO8E2A3BlgIZEDOwATgJZwDmFWUAHgPx2Mt2aAL5o0eaABUA7gHsoydJ1zhSRbDNnlKmAEb9mbDlhB8o9Q0NHjVUAKIAbCAFsFsBFAA+UTWIDGsnD0UAEOTn7ATIFEAIIMDFQgADyOLgB8bgDaOqg4EoTECNgANDnKVAXYAG5UDgCupKWcylyVVHCywAAWEAwlOcJNWCh5qpWa-c1Y2LqVNfWNA0OYIyr46iTYS1AA9DtQ3Uy0UBBOzhBwwOZdsnUOACYn8bIMUNI9cAc9UABmdXARKKfI4hWpOe5oAC6YiAA)

Comment: Thanks! That example assumes that I can set up the collection with type safety in advance (you use the union in the array type). I am specifically trying to solve for the case where that is not possible because user may have input elements that do not correctly match. I must be able to take as input an array with data whose structure may be wrong, extract values whose structure are right, and return them as instances of the corresponding types.

Comment: typescript doesn't exist at runtime

Comment: The type information does not need to exist at runtime. If every element in the array was NOT appropriately structured, it would be OK for the result to be an empty array because it was impossible to cast each element to `One` or `Two`. This is expressible at compile time because each if the elements don't match the key structure of `One | Two` they are allowed to map to `never` by throwing error.

Comment: "user may have input elements that do not correctly match" - user input is not available at compile time

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to use Zod to define the types One and Two, which gives you the by-product of runtime validators. Then it's a trivial matter to get a matching item.

Here's a worked example that you can see and run at [this repl](https://replit.com/@cefn/ZodDemo?v=1#index.ts)...

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const ONE_SCHEMA = z.object({
  type: z.literal("One"),
  a: z.string(),
  x: z.string().optional()
})
type One = z.infer<typeof ONE_SCHEMA>

const TWO_SCHEMA = z.object({
  type: z.literal("Two"),
  b: z.string(),
  y: z.string().optional()
})
type Two = z.infer<typeof TWO_SCHEMA>

function validate(map: Map<string, string>): One | Two | null {
  try {
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(map.entries());
    return z.union([
      ONE_SCHEMA,
      TWO_SCHEMA
    ]).parse(obj);
  }
  catch (error) {
    return null
  }
}

function validateAndPrint(map: Map<string, string>) {
  console.log(validate(map))
}

validateAndPrint(new Map([
  ["type", "One"],
  ["a", "value"],
  ["x", "another"],
]))

validateAndPrint(new Map([
  ["type", "Two"],
  ["b", "value"],
]))

validateAndPrint(new Map([
  ["type", "One"],
]))
```